# How to create tabs in jquery?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am developing ui tabs, but having problem with the tab that its working properly when I newly click on tab , when I again click on another tab its not working properly.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-head">
        <li class="head tab-act">tab 1</li>
        <li class="head">tab 2</li>
        <li class="head">tab 3</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content tab1 act-tab">tab content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-content tab2 ">tab content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-content tab3">tab content 3</div>
</div>
```

And jquery

```
$('.tab-head').on('click', 'li', function (e) {
    var curIndex = $(this).index();
    $('.tab-act').removeClass('tab-act');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass("act-tab");
    $(this).addClass('tab-act');
    $('.tab-content').eq(curIndex).slideDown(1000).addClass('act-tab');
});
```

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Can you check in firebug if you are getting any javascript error or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this. Initially hide the .tab-content using css.

```
<style>
         .tab-content { display : none; }
</style>
```

your Jquery be :

```
$('.tab-head').on('click','li', function(e){

var curIndex = $(this).index();
$('.tab-act').removeClass('tab-act');
$('.tab-content').removeClass("act-tab");

$(this).addClass('tab-act');

$('.tab-content').hide(); // extra line i will be added here

$('.tab-content').eq(curIndex).slideDown(1000).addClass('act-tab');
});
```

Look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9YKXy/)

Answer (score 1):

your re-inventing the wheel,

use JQuery UI tabs:

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

this will replace your code with:

```
$(function() {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
} );
```

and the HTML..

```
<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
   <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
  </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
   <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
   <div id="tabs-3">
   <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
<p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i prefer u to use some framework like bootstrap or "jquery UI"
You can find out good documentaion about here

https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

it is so easy to use and have many other benefits for you

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Content for Tab 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Content for Tab 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
   background-color: #eef;     
}

#tabs {
    width: 95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```